# Angular 2/4 *ngIf performance slow when rendering different component states (new, edit, read)

Tags: angular

I have an Angular (v4.1.1) application that uses `*ngIf` in many places on my form entry component to show/hide elements that are meant for new, edit or read-only mode. When I test, I see that it sometimes takes a few seconds to render the form as a result of waiting for the data to return. This results in some things being shown initially that shouldn't be there.

Here's a small example of what the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="col">
  <h1>{{list.displayName || 'Create New List'}}</h1>
  <p *ngIf="isNew" class="text-muted">Complete the form below and click 'save'</p>
</div>
<div id="toolbar" class="col">
  <div class="text-right">
    <button *ngIf="!editMode" (click)="cancel()" class="btn btn-outline-warning clickable">Close</button>
    <button *ngIf="editMode" (click)="cancel()" class="btn btn-outline-warning clickable">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is what is the best way to handle form state? Is it better have a separate component for each state so the rendering is faster and specific to the action? But this way seems like a lot of duplication, though.

Comment: make the vaiaable `false` at starting, then change it to `true` or `false` depending the result. So that the things will not be shown initially

Comment: So that's what I'm doing already but the UI jumps around flipping buttons, changing inputs to values, changing headers, etc. Is this really the best way to manage form state?

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable `false` at starting, then change it to true or false depending the result. 
So that the things will not be shown initially

for example, initialize `editMode` as false.

Here is an example(expert),

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  editMode = false;
  constructor() { }

  getMode(): void {
    this.Service.getMode().then(mode => if(mode == 'edit'){ editMode = true} else { editMode = false });
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMode();
  }

}
```

Comment: take a variable `waiting` and make it true on api response, and give the *ngIf="variable" on entire form..so that it will be completely in invisible  state